# Android - Is it ok to put @IntDef values inside @interface?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I'm trying to implement `@IntDef` annotation in Android development.

**First Method**: it looks great with the definition separated in a `Constant.java` class:

```
public class Constant {
   @IntDef(value={SORT_PRICE, SORT_TIME, SORT_DURATION})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
   public @interface SortType{}
   public static final int SORT_PRICE = 0;
   public static final int SORT_TIME = 1;
   public static final int SORT_DURATION = 2;
}
```

Usage:

```
@Constant.SortType int sortType = Constant.SORT_PRICE;
```

But things get a lot messier when there's multiple definition (e.g UserType, StoreType, etc) in one file.

**Second Method:** So I came up with something like this to separate values between definition:

```
public class Constant {
   @IntDef(value={SortType.SORT_PRICE, SortType.SORT_TIME, SortType.SORT_DURATION})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
   public @interface SortTypeDef{}

   public static class SortType{
       public static final int PRICE = 0;
       public static final int TIME = 1;
       public static final int DURATION = 2;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Constant.SortTypeDef int sortType = Constant.SortType.PRICE;
```

But as you can see, I created two different name for it: `SortTypeDef` and `SortType`

**Third Method:** I tried to move the list of possible values inside `@interface`:

```
public class Constant {
   @IntDef(value={SortType.SORT_PRICE, SortType.SORT_TIME, SortType.SORT_DURATION})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
   public @interface SortType{
       int PRICE = 0;
       int TIME = 1;
       int DURATION = 2;
   }
}
```

Usage

```
@Constant.SortType int sortType = Constant.SortType.PRICE;
```

While it does work, I don't know what is the drawback.
Is it okay to put the possible values of `@IntDef` inside `@interface`? Is there any performance differences across the three methods above?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question?  I am wondering the same now...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky not yet, but I'm continuing to use the third method on production code and so far got no problem. I think the best way to check is by profiling (usage, number of constant, etc).

Comment: The IntDef annotation has only RetentionPolicy.SOURCE and is therefore only used by compiler annotation processors. It's not possible for it to have an effect on runtime performance unless the annotation processor is doing something very esoteric, such as using bytecode weaving or code generation to insert runtime checks into your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer**: for simple projects, it is OK, but for more complex ones the first method is preferred.

**Long answer**: 
Although bytecode for `sortType` is identical in all three cases, there is a difference.  The key lies in the `Retention` annotation, which sets retention policy to `SOURCE`.  That means that your `SortType` annotation is "[to be discarded by the compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)", so bytecode for annotation itself is not generated.

First method defines regular static fields outside the annotations, with the regular bytecode generated for them.  Second and third cases define constants within annotations, and bytecode for the constants is not generated.

If compiler has access to the source file containing your `SortType` declaration, either method is fine and bytecode for `sortType` is identical.  But if source code is not accessible (e.g. you have only compiled library), annotation is not accessible.  For the first approach, only annotation itself is not accessible, but for the latter ones, constants values are not accessible too.

I used to prefer the third method as the most clean and structured.  I used to until one day I ran into an issue: when I started writing Espresso  tests for that code, compiler did not have access to the source code defining the annotation.  I had to either switch to the canonical `IntDef` declaration or to use integer values instead of symbolic constants for the test.

So the bottom line is:

- stick to the canonical way unless your annotation is internal to your code and you do not refer to it from anywhere else, including tests

Answer (score 4):

To make your third method working, you should name `values` like in the interface.
I used your code and make it works:

```
public class Constant {
    @IntDef(value = {SortType.PRICE, SortType.TIME, SortType.DURATION})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @interface SortType {
        int PRICE = 0;
        int TIME = 1;
        int DURATION = 2;
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class Constant {
    @IntDef(value = {SortType.SORT_PRICE, SortType.SORT_TIME, SortType.SORT_DURATION})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @interface SortType {
        int SORT_PRICE = 0;
        int SORT_TIME = 1;
        int SORT_DURATION = 2;
    }
}
```

Usage for second:

```
@Constant.SortType int sortType = Constant.SortType.SORT_DURATION;
```

Pick one, both should work.

Answer (score 1):

I came here hoping to find why the Android docs show your first method, but the third method has been working fine for me in production code for months. I haven't seen any reason not to do it that way. As you said, it cleans up the namespace when you might have multiple sets of related constants.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good place for an enum...

```
public enum SortEnum {
    DURATION,
    PRICE,
    TIME;
}
```

Comment: idk, I've been avoiding enum since I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE. Granted that video is 2 y.o and many things may have changed.

Comment: IntDefs are specifically designed to be Enum replacements in resource constrained systems. Recommending replacing them with Enums neither answers the question nor contributes to the conversation.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the Enum issues in Android until Ahmad pointed it out. Been using Java forever, but not Android until very recently, and it appeared to me the OP was implementing an anti-pattern. But, since researching what appears to be an issue with Enums on Android I will be avoiding them and checking out IntDefs.

Comment: @NinePlanFailed If you use proguard you can use enums with no problem as proguard will replace them when compiling for release.